# handle data from json autocomplete response

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, append

I'm getting this type of response from jquery autocomplete plugin:

```
    {"data":{
                "events":{"id":"96","value":"Nr 1 Offline","abbrev":"image.jpg"},
                "users":{"id":"9346","value":"John":"avatar.jpg"}
              }
}
```

Now, how can I handle this data ? For example:

1. to alert some users name; or
2. to append his avatar image to am `<img>` tag;

   I'm new to jquery-ui, so an small example will help me very much.

Answer (score 1):

> for example to alert some users name or to append his avatar image to am  tag ? i'm new to jquery ui, so an small example will help me very much

Alerting an user name:

```
$data = {"data":{
            "events":{"id":"96","value":"Nr 1 Offline","abbrev":"image.jpg"},
            "users":{"id":"9346","value":"John", "avatar":"avatar.jpg"}
          }
    }//Note please I've added an "avatar" key to your $data

 alert($data.data.users.value);
```

Appending his avatar image to an img tag:

```
$data = {"data":{
            "events":{"id":"96","value":"Nr 1 Offline","abbrev":"image.jpg"},
            "users":{"id":"9346","value":"John", "avatar":"avatar.jpg"}
          }
    }; //Note please I've added an "avatar" key to your $data

 $("#your-image-id").attr("src", $data.data.users.avatar);
```

I hoped it helped. Cheers